# Problema com ponto em passagem de parametro post no slim framework

Tags: php

Meu webService utiliza o slim framework e funciona corretamente usando essa requisição:

```
http://localhost:8000/wsrf/cadastrarFarmaciasPlantao/TESTEA/38410101/38410202/38410303/35172062/Rua X/email@emailcom/site/2015-10-15/IMAGEM01JPG
```

mas se eu adicionar um ponto no e-mail ou na extensão da imagem deixa de funcionar

```
http://localhost:8000/wsrf/cadastrarFarmaciasPlantao/TESTEA/38410101/38410202/38410303/35172062/Rua X/email@email.com/site/2015-10-15/IMAGEM01.JPG
```

Alguém sabe a causa?

Cabeçalho php da requisição:

```
$app->post("/cadastrarFarmaciasPlantao/:nome/:telefone/:telefone2/:telefone3/:cep/:endereco/:email/:site/:data/:imagem", 
        function ($nome,$telefone,$telefone2,$telefone3,$cep,$endereco,$email,$site,$data,$imagem)
```

Comment: O `@` é um simbolo reservado em url, ele serve para passar user:pass no url. Provavelmente o ponto faz ativar essa funcionalidade. Deves usar `%40` e depois descodificar o url quando fôres usar. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score -2):

Obrigado pela resposta, mas meu problema era com o . com o @ não tive problemas

Resolvi meu problema opitando por passar o parâmetro pelo header ao invés da url.

Comment: Gente estou tento problemas com pontos no slim 4, mas acho que deve ser um bug, uma solução temporária é usar $request->getQueryParams() usando => exemplo?params=value